# Is there any way to modify a nested classes implementation in it's children?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, inner-classes

I want to have a class interface (let's call it class A) that can be inherited and implemented differently throughout my code, and that interface contains some functions, including an stl type iterator, which is defined as a nested class.

My problem is that whenever i try to inherit the interface (into a let's call class B), as well as the iterator, and implement them, the begin and end of the inherited class expect an iterator of type A::iterator, even though the iterator in the B class inherits from A::iterator. I know that polymorphism works only with pointers/references, but how would i be able to do this one?

I also tried doing it with friend classes, but i don't really know that well how they work, as I've never used them before, so it turned out kind of messy. Here is some example code (the one that i actually run)

```
class A
{
public:
    class iterator 
    {
    public:
        virtual Entity& operator*() const = 0;
        virtual bool operator!=(const iterator) const = 0;
        virtual bool valid() const = 0;
        virtual iterator& operator=(const iterator& it) = 0;
        virtual iterator operator++() = 0;
        virtual iterator operator++(int) = 0;
        virtual ~iterator() {};
    };
    virtual int add(const std::vector<std::string>& params) = 0;
    virtual int remove(const std::vector<std::string>& params) = 0;
    virtual int update(const std::vector<std::string>& params) = 0;
    virtual int save(const std::vector<std::string>& params) = 0;
    virtual int size() = 0;
    virtual typename iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual typename iterator end() = 0;
    virtual ~A() {}
};


class B: public A
{
private:
    std::vector<Entity> elements;
public:
    class iterator : public A::iterator
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Entity>::iterator ptr;
        B& repo;
    public:
        iterator(std::vector<Entity>::iterator ptr, B& container) : ptr{ ptr }, repo{ container }{}
        Entity& operator*() const override;
        bool operator!=(const iterator) const override;
        bool valid() const override;
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& it) override;
        iterator operator++() override;
        iterator operator++(int) override;
    };
    B() : elements{ std::vector<Entity>() } {}
    int add(const std::vector<std::string>& params) override;
    int remove(const std::vector<std::string>& params) override;
    int update(const std::vector<std::string>& params) override;
    int save(const std::vector<std::string>& params) override;
    int size() override;
    typename iterator begin();
    typename iterator end();
    ~B() {};
};
```

The reason i want to do this is because i have to create 2 different repositories, one working with a file and one in memory, and maybe a future one requiring a database, but i just can't get the iterator right by inheriting it. Returning an std::vector would be a lot faster but also kind of cheating.
EDIT: What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is to have two repositories that have the same interface and that can also be iterated through, one of them implemented on an std::vector and the other one directly on a file. That means that the iterator for the vector repo would have to just give me the const std::vector iterator and the other one would have to open a file, go to the next line, etc in a read only manner. I have to make them compatible with the range based for loop.

Comment: Sorry about that. I pulled the comment because I'm not sure I understand the question, and my replacement comment is taking too long to write.

Comment: It's fine. My B::iterator is implemented in a cpp file, separately from this header. But this shouldn't matter, the issue is that the program says that B::begin() and B::end() do not return the same type as A::begin() and A::end(), which is right, because in A i return an A::iterator and in B i return a B::iterator. But B::iterator inherits from A::iterator, which makes it an A::iterator as well, so i don't realize what the issue is and why it doesn't want to compile it as such.

Comment: You want all children of `A` to implement an Iterator. You've done that. All of the child iterators can be different, but will still support the generic interface defined by `A::iterator`. What we have here is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a solution to a problem that is creating more problems. You will likely be better off revising the question to ask about the problem you're trying to solve with this solution.

Comment: Did the edit, sorry for being unclear with what i wanted to achieve.

Comment: Because of the is-a relationship, you could use references to `B::iterator` through `A::iterator`, but that's just weird. Iterator's supposed to mask smurf like that. What if you add another layer of abstraction? In this case, `A::iterator` is not really the iterator. It is a wrapper that hides the fact that it holds a reference to a `B::iterator` (or a anything that implements the `A::private_iterator` interface).

Comment: Wouldn't that create a circular dependency? B would depend on the wrapper defined in A to hold it's iterator and A would depend on the implementation of B to provide functionality. Or i may probably misunderstand what you mean by the wrapper in A holding a reference to B::iterator.

Comment: All `A::Iterator` knows is it contains a reference to a `A::private_iterator`. It knows nothing about what that reference really references. `B` needs to know about `A`, but not the reverse. By the way, watch out for stuff like `virtual iterator operator++() = 0;` Because `iterator` is pure virtual you can't have an instance, making it impossible to return one by value.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually, thanks for pointing that out. I'll try tomorrow to modify it so that instead it works with references and i'll keep you notified if i manage to succeed with it, probably as an answer to this post. Thanks lots for your help and time!

Comment: If you really want a type-erased iterator, the publicly used iterator type could be a wrapper which contains a pointer to the actual abstract interface. The iterator type's copy constructor and copy assignment should use a virtual `clone()` of the implementation object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a type-erasure: a type that supports different implementations, but can be used by other code as just a single type, as that type, not just by pointer and reference, can be copied, etc. The usual way of setting this up is a non-polymorphic class which contains a pointer to a polymorphic interface:

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Entity {};

class A
{
protected:
    class IterInterface
    {
    public:
        virtual ~IterInterface() = default;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> clone() const = 0;
        virtual Entity& dereference() const = 0;
        virtual void increment() = 0;
        virtual bool equal_to(const IterInterface& other) const = 0;
    };

    virtual std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> begin_impl() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> end_impl() = 0;

public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = Entity;
        using reference = Entity&;
        using pointer = Entity*;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

        iterator() = default;
        iterator(const iterator& it)
        {
            if (it.m_impl)
                m_impl = it.m_impl->clone();
        }
        iterator(iterator&&) noexcept = default;
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& it)
        {
            if (it.m_impl)
                m_impl = it.m_impl->clone(); // self-assignment-safe
            else
                m_impl = nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& operator=(iterator&&) noexcept = default;

        explicit iterator(std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> && impl)
            : m_impl(std::move(impl)) {}

        Entity& operator*() const
        { return m_impl->dereference(); }

        iterator& operator++()
        { m_impl->increment(); return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) const
        {
            iterator copy = *this;
            m_impl->increment();
            return copy;
        }

        friend bool operator==(const iterator &it1, const iterator &it2)
        {
            bool it1_ok(it1.m_impl);
            bool it2_ok(it2.m_impl);
            if (it1_ok && it2_ok)
                return it1.m_impl->equal_to(*it2.m_impl);
            else
                return it1_ok == it2_ok;
        }
        friend bool operator!=(const iterator &it1, const iterator &it2)
        { return !(it1 == it2); }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> m_impl;
    };

    iterator begin()
    { return iterator(begin_impl()); }
    iterator end()
    { return iterator(end_impl()); }

    // ...
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    // ...
private:
    std::vector<Entity> elements;

    class IterImpl : public IterInterface
    {
    public:
        explicit IterImpl(std::vector<Entity>::iterator viter)
            : m_viter(viter) {}

        std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> clone() const override
        { return std::make_unique<IterImpl>(m_viter); }

        Entity& dereference() const override { return *m_viter; }

        void increment() override { ++m_viter; }

        bool equal_to(const IterInterface& other) const override
        {
            if (auto* oimpl = dynamic_cast<const IterImpl*>(&other))
                return m_viter == oimpl->m_viter;
            // "other" isn't even from a B.
            return false;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Entity>::iterator m_viter;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> begin_impl() override
    { return std::make_unique<IterImpl>(elements.begin()); }

    std::unique_ptr<IterInterface> end_impl() override
    { return std::make_unique<IterImpl>(elements.end()); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue quite bluntly to say so, by returning references to iterator rather than objects. With that i always have to keep a pointer that i can reference and return in the main function, but at least it works. The problem is as someone mentioned in the comments: polymorphism only works with pointers and references.